# in how many ways can 4 distinct people fit in 2 distinct rooms?

Tags: combinations

I tried doing this by brute force and I tried doing 4! And get 24. Is that correct and is there a better way doing this?

Comment: Call the people A, B, C, D. There are $2$ ways to choose where A goes. For each choice, there are $2$ ways to choose where B goes. And so on.

Comment: If the question insists that there is at least 1 person in each room, then there will be 2 less ways.